# Is there a way to find which API Parameters are valid without a documentation?

Tags: javascript, python, json, api, networking

I have access to a typical web API that takes a parameter `getUser: id` which will return a name.

Like so (python):

```
    import requests
    import json
    r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps({"getUser": 1}))
    response = r.json()
    print(response)
```

The above code will return a dict with a username that belongs to the specified ID (1).

Without having access to any documentation, is it possible to know if other params are valid?

I've already tried obvious ones like `setUser` `getID` etc, but none of my attempts are valid.

Is there a way to examine the options somehow? Like a "help" command or similar? I could try and "bruteforce" my way through with common params, but I'm not sure if the host would like that. If what I'm trying to do is futile and impossible, please let me know.

Comment: No.
(filler text)

Comment: @MohitC 
That's fair enough, I didn't expect a solution, but I had to try and see if there was a way. Thanks for the reply